# Create cypher statement which create or update existed(or not existed) relationship and props

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create chyper statement that:

1. If relationship is not existed between two nodes I create it
2. Modify the properties on it.

So I came up with this:

```
String modifyRelations="match (p1:User),(p2:User) " +
                    "WHERE p1.userId=~{1} and p2.userId=~{2} "+
                    "MERGE (p1)-[r:follow]->(p2)"+
                    "SET follow.followType={3}";


        final PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(modifyRelations);
            ps1.setString(1, sourceNodeDTO.getUserId());
            ps1.setString(2, targetNodeDTO.getUserId());
            ps1.setString(3, followTypes.getValue());
```

I got error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax, message=follow not defined
```

The thing is that I dont want to create new relationship in case it already existed.

If existed I only want to modify the property (follow) inside it.
But if the relation is not existed I want to create it and set into it the follow property

Thank you,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

## Answer to Original Question

It looks like the only thing you *absolutely* need to change is your `SET` clause. It needs to reference the relationship by its identifier (`r`), not its relationship type:

```
"SET r.followType={3}";
```

The `MERGE` clause will only create a new `follow` relationship between the matched `p1` and `p2` nodes if one does not already exist. It will match (and not create) an existing `follow` relationship even it has additional property keys/values.

However, you *should* also change the `WHERE` clause, since your regular expression is doing nothing for you that a direct string comparison would not also do. In Cypher, a regular expression matches the *entire value*, and since your regular expressions use no wild cards and are not case insensitive, you should just use a simple string comparison. A regular expression is also slower than a simple string comparison.

```
String modifyRelations=
    "MATCH (p1:User), (p2:User) " +
    "WHERE p1.userId={1} and p2.userId={2} "+
    "MERGE (p1)-[r:follow]->(p2)"+
    "SET r.followType={3}";
```

## Answer to Question in Comments

To answer your follow-on question in the comments below, this query will also create `p1` and/or `p2` if either do not yet exist:

```
String modifyRelations=
    "MERGE (p1:User {userId: {1}})" +
    "MERGE (p2:User {userId: {2}})" +
    "MERGE (p1)-[r:follow]->(p2)"+
    "SET follow.followType={3}";
```

Comment: That worked. thanks. Could you please upgrade this statement and also add on the same query that could create the two nodes with the relationships in case they not exist. ? and if they exist just to update the relationship on them thank you.

Comment: You currently use a regular expression on each of your `WHERE` clauses. When creating a `User` (if no matching `User` is found), what do you want to use for `userId`? Or, is it OK to just get rid of the regular expressions altogether?

Comment: userId is Index in my graph. Its primary key and is uniqe. in case userId is not exit I would like to create new node that contains that userId property on the graph. same goes for the other user(p2)

Comment: See my updated answer. It looks to like you do not need to use regular expressions at all (nor should you).

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up variable/identifier (which is `r` in your case) and relationship-type which is `follow`.

It is good practice to all-caps the rel-type, then it is more obvious.

I.e. `FOLLOWS`.

```
MATCH (p1:User),(p2:User)
WHERE p1.userId=~{1} and p2.userId=~{2} 
MERGE (p1)-[r:FOLLOW]->(p2)
ON CREATE SET SET r.followType={3}
```

And you also *probably* want to use `ON CREATE SET` instead of just plain, unconditional `SET`.